# Abstract does not appear after the article title

Tags: compilation-error

I am using svjour3.cls format from Springer and when I compile my article, I see the abstract and keywords in a sperate page and does not appear after the title.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\smartqed 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
%\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
 \captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} 
%\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
#1\end{tabular}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % 
%\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
 \frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\makeatletter
 \def\endthebibliography{%
\def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' 
 environment}}%
\endlist
}
\makeatother
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\journalname{Applied Intelligence}

\begin{document}
\title{Trust in ABM}

\author{A.D         \and
    Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{A. D \at
          first address \\
          Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
          Fax: +123-45-678910\\
          \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\

       \and
       S. Author \at
          second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Interactions are the building blocks of open environments. Finding reliable partners to interact with in open environments is a challenging task for agents, therefore, trust and reputation mechanisms are used to handle this issue. In literature, various trust mechanisms have been described. This article presents an extensive review of the most representative trust and reputation models presented in literature. 
\keywords{trust \and Second reputation \and agent}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
blabla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is seriously deprecated and should no longer be employed. Load either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package instead.

Comment: @Mico This one does not solve the problem. I changed sunfigure to subfig. Still the same output.

Comment: Still off-topic: Don't load packages more than once. Case in point: the `caption` package. Separately, you shouldn't be defining the `L` column type more than once.

Comment: @Mico Non of them helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: Did I *claim* these comments were designed to "solve your problem"? My commens were deliberately prefaced by the label "off-topic"...

Comment: No you did not and I did not ask for other stylish problems in my text. But, thank you for telling me.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @samcarter they did not solve the problem.

Comment: @AH2012 If Micos and Zarkos answers did not solve https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425005/extra-vertical-lines-in-tabularx-package you should explain which aspects of your question are still open.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted causes error messages during compilation, so there is no point at looking at the broken document and worrying about the missing abstract.

If the errors are fixed, the abstract is properly displayed. In detail the problems are

- you cannot have `#1\end{tabular}}` in your preamble
- you cannot have an empty line in `\institute`

Besides this, you should consider implementing Micos comments, they are not merely "style" problems, but are prone to cause problems.

---

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\smartqed 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
%\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
 \captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} 
%\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
%#1\end{tabular}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % 
%\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
 \frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\makeatletter
 \def\endthebibliography{%
\def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' 
 environment}}%
\endlist
}
\makeatother
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\journalname{Applied Intelligence}

\begin{document}
\title{Trust in ABM}

\author{A.D         \and
    Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{A. D \at
          first address \\
          Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
          Fax: +123-45-678910\\
          \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
       \and
       S. Author \at
          second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Interactions are the building blocks of open environments. Finding reliable partners to interact with in open environments is a challenging task for agents, therefore, trust and reputation mechanisms are used to handle this issue. In literature, various trust mechanisms have been described. This article presents an extensive review of the most representative trust and reputation models presented in literature. 
\keywords{trust \and Second reputation \and agent}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
blabla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter, \end{tabular} is commented and empty line of institute does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AH2012 Did you try the exact same code as in my answer or did you test with your document? As you can see from the screenshot, the code from my answer displays the abstract.

Comment: Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.